# Unicode full width to standard ASCII (and back) in Python

Tags: python, unicode

I need a method to convert a string from standard ASCII and Unicode FULLWIDTH characters and vice versa in pure Python 2.6. The string may also contain symbols.

I tried unicodedata.normalize but it doesn't convert symbols, and that is one-way. Other solutions found in other questions don't work well for my program (many don't convert symbols).

I am trying to create a savefile reader/writer for the PS2. For example I read this string from the file:

```
'\x82g\x82\x81\x82\x8c\x82\x86\x81|\x82k\x82\x89\x82\x86\x82\x85\x82r\x82\x99\x82\x93\x82\x94\x82\x85\x82\x8d\x81@\x82c\x82\x81\x82\x94\x82\x81'
```

that is `s-jis`-encoded, I decode it with `.decode('s-jis')`:

```
u'\uff28\uff41\uff4c\uff46\u2212\uff2c\uff49\uff46\uff45\uff33\uff59\uff53\uff54\uff45\uff4d\u3000\uff24\uff41\uff54\uff41'
```

and I print it:

```
Ｈａｌｆ−ＬｉｆｅＳｙｓｔｅｍ　Ｄａｔａ
```

this is the FULLWIDTH string that I need to convert to ASCII; it should become this:

```
'Half-LifeSystem Data'
```

(there is nothing between `Life` and `System`)

Note that I chose this save because it contains the two most recurring symbols, `-` and the space.

Also, I must be able to re-encode it the same way it was, because the user may rename the save, so I have to take the string from the input dialog and write it to the file again.

Comment: The simple "conversion" is to scan through the string array and remove every other byte (which is always 0xFF sine this is standard ASCII)

Comment: You'd need to create your own ASCII-to-fullwidth-codepoint mapping, I think. The Unicode normalisation database does give you wide-to-ascii mappings I see, but not vice versa. That is not a Python limitation.

Comment: @Floris: No, that is not the correct mapping. `U+FF48` is *lowercase* `H`, so ASCII 0x68.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you are right, I spoke too soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use a [`unicode.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to map between the two sets; the characters map one-to-one:

```
ascii_to_wide = dict((i, unichr(i + 0xfee0)) for i in range(0x21, 0x7f))
ascii_to_wide.update({0x20: u'\u3000', 0x2D: u'\u2212'})  # space and minus
wide_to_ascii = dict((i, unichr(i - 0xfee0)) for i in range(0xff01, 0xff5f))
wide_to_ascii.update({0x3000: u' ', 0x2212: u'-'})        # space and minus

wide_text.translate(wide_to_ascii)
ascii_text.translate(ascii_to_wide)

>>> wide_text.translate(wide_to_ascii)
u'Half-LifeSystem Data'
>>> wide_text.translate(wide_to_ascii).translate(ascii_to_wide)
u'\uff28\uff41\uff4c\uff46\u2212\uff2c\uff49\uff46\uff45\uff33\uff59\uff53\uff54\uff45\uff4d\u3000\uff24\uff41\uff54\uff41'
```

Comment: Not quite. What about \u2212 ?

Comment: `wide_text.translate(wide_to_ascii)` returns the same `wide_text` for me

Comment: @LordSpectre: yeah, I had my table generation wrong, corrected.

Comment: Now it's `SyntaxError` (I think it's Python 3)

Comment: @LordSpectre: No, you have Python 2.6, I assumed 2.7, will correct, and see about U+2212 as well.

Comment: Ok now it converts the words, but not the symbols. (`u'Half\u2212LifeSystem\u3000Data`)

Comment: @LordSpectre: That is what I said, I added mappings for those. You need individual mappings for all those exceptions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add other symbols as I encounter them

Comment: U+2212, MINUS SIGN, is neither ASCII nor wide ASCII, so it does not belong to the scope of “Unicode full width to standard ASCII (and back)”. If there is a need to operate on such characters, too, the conversion task should first be defined exactly.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: exactly; the use of U+2212 shows the original data was generated with a manual mapping too, to generate data that fits wholesale in the s-jis codec.